# can we assign an Exception Class object to the reference of Object class object

Tags: java, class, object

why this is will not work, can any one give the exact answer for this one....

```
public class Manager
{
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
         try{

                 Object obj=new A();   //it will generate ClassNotFoundException object
                 System.out.println("currently the reference obj is pointer to the object:"+obj);

            }catch(Object o)
                  {
                      System.out.println(o);
                  }

        }

     System.out.println("End of Main");
}
```

Comment: Wrap your object in an Exception, then throw the Exception instead. Inside the Catch clause, you can then find the object via the Exception.

Answer (score 7):

That won't work simply because the variable declared in the "catch" statement has to be an exception type (i.e. `Throwable` or a subtype).

From [section 14.20](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.20) of the Java Language Specification:

> A catch clause must have exactly one
>   parameter (which is called an
>   exception parameter); the declared
>   type of the exception parameter must
>   be the class Throwable or a subclass
>   (not just a subtype) of Throwable, or
>   a compile-time error occurs.In
>   particular, it is a compile-time error
>   if the declared type of the exception
>   parameter is a type variable (§4.4).
>   The scope of the parameter variable is
>   the Block of the catch clause.

Of course you *could* write:

```
catch(Throwable t)
{
    Object o = t;
    System.out.println(o);
}
```

It's not clear why you'd want to though.

Answer (score 0):

You said nothing about class A's constructor... Is it actually throwing an exception ?
If yes, then the other answers should help you out.
If no, then perhaps I might recall that **instanciating** an exception is not **throwing** an exception...

Examples :

This won't work :

```
try {
 new Exception();
} catch (Exception e) {
 System.out.println("This will never be printed...");
}
```

However you can get the intended result by adding the `throw` keyword :

```
try {
 throw new Exception();
} catch (Exception e) {
 System.out.println("This will actually be printed...");
}
```